# Divide dataGrid in sessions with Flex 3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, datagrid, actionscript, flex3

So, what I want is to make a dataGrid divided in parts, like this:

```
Column 1    Column 2    Column 3    Column N
data1_r1    data2_r1    data3_r1    data4_r1
data1_r2    data2_r2    data3_r2    data4_r2
data1_r3    data2_r3    data3_r3    data4_r3
                  Session 2         
data1_r5    data2_r5    data3_r5    data4_r5
data1_r6    data2_r6    data3_r6    data4_r6
data1_r7    data2_r7    data3_r7    data4_r7
                  Session 3
```

Basically what I want is that. The sessions are dynamics (I don't know how many registers comes before each session, neither I know how many sessions will be, but I can count in execution time).

- I can also divide each session into one separated ArrayCollection
- I can put them all into one single ArrayCollection
- I also can (if necessary) put a register between them, like in the example showed. For instance, it would be like "Session 2" were the dataProvider.getItemAt(3) object and Session 3 were dataProvider.getItemAt(7).

Is it possible and if it is what should I be looking for to help me with this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You may consider using an AdvancedDataGrid with hierarchical data.  [More info on that here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7bf4.html).

For your situation, I think you'd need a "session" object; which can be as easy as an object like this:

```
package com.something.something
{
    import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

    public class SessionObject
    {
        public function SessionObject()
        {
        }

        public var label :String;
        public var children :ArrayCollection 
    }
}
```

Each element of the "Children" collection inside your session object would each represent one of your sub rows.  Conceptually they'd be an object like this:

```
package com.something.something
{
    import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

    public class SessionData
    {
        public function SessionData()
        {
        }

        public var column1 :String;
        public var column2 :String;
        public var column3 :String;
        public var column4 :String;
    }
}
```

Then display it something like this:

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid width="100%" height="100%">
    <mx:dataProvider>
        <mx:HierarchicalData source="{dpHierarchy}"/>
    </mx:dataProvider>
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="label"/>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="column1 "/>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="column2" />
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="column3"/>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="column4"/>
    </mx:columns>
</mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
```

Things can get harder if you really have an unknown number of columns at compile time; but you can create the columns array in ActionScript "on the fly" at runtime if you need to.

Comment: Columns are known and static, what's dynamic is the amount of session and the amount of records in each session.

Comment: Then creating your data in a structure I define is probably the answer.